# Split shell output and convert to excel

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have wrote a script. It takes ouput from database and store in text file. It display the output like

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

I want it to be displayed as

```
A   B
C   D
E    F
```

It should be converted to excel file

Kindly tell the Linux shell script command

Comment: What have you tried on your own? What do you expect this script to be written in?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Convert your file to a csv-file**

A quick and dirty method, that will only work if your input-data does not contain spaces and/or `;`:

```bash
$ paste - - < yourfile | awk 'OFS=";" {print $1,$2}' | tee outputfile.csv
A;B
C;D
E;F
```

If your data does contain spaces and/or `;`, you will need to use specialised tools such as `miller`:

```bash
$ paste - - < yourfile | tee tabsep 
A   B
C   D
E   F

$ mlr --ifs tab --ofs comma --quote-all --ocsv --headerless-csv-output cat tabsep \
| tee outputfile.csv
"A","B"
"C","D"
"E","F"
```

You can install `miller` with your distros package-manager or [get it from github](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller).

**2. Load `outputfile.csv` into Excel and save it in your desired format.**